# error: package androidx.work does not exist

Tags: android, androidx

I create a new project from Android studio and when trying to use androidx.work, see the error 'error: package androidx.work does not exist'

I can see most of the other androidx packages such as activity, core, loader etc.., but just not 'work'. Has latest and greatest updates.

project gradle.properties

```
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below library in your app level gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1-rc01'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:2.0.1-rc01'
```